# Javascript create variable from its name

Tags: javascript

In PHP we can do this:

```
$variable = "name_of_variable";
$this->{$variable} = "somevalue";
```

how to do this in javascript?

where use case should look like:

```
function Apple(){
    var name = "variable_name";
    this.(name) = "value";
}
console.log(new Apple());
```

to output

```
[Apple: {variable_name:"value"}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
this[name] = "value";
```

All objects can use dot and array notation for variable access.

Also note, this will allow you to create name value pairs that are *inaccessible* via dot notation:

```
var foo = {};
foo['bar-baz'] = 'fizzbuzz';
alert(foo.bar-baz); //this will not work because `-` is subtraction
alert(foo['bar-baz']); //this will work fine
```

If you are creating a new object literal, you can use string literals for the names for values with special characters:

```
var foo  = {'bar-baz':'fizzbuzz'};
```

But you will not be able to use variables as the `key` within an object literal because they are interpreted as the name to use:

```
var foo = 'fizz';
var bar = { foo:'buzz' }
alert( bar.fizz ); //this will not work because `foo` was the key provided
alert( bar.foo ); //alerts 'buzz'
```

Because other answerers are mentioning `eval`, I will explain a case where `eval` could be useful.

### Warning! Code using `eval` is `evil`, proceed with caution.

If you need to use a variable with a dynamic name, and that variable does not exist on another object.

It's important to know that calling `var foo` in the global context attaches the new variable to the global object (typically `window`). In a closure, however, the variable created by `var foo` exists only within the context of the closure, and is not attached to any particular object.

If you need a dynamic variable name within a closure it is better to use a container object:

```
var container = {};
container[foo] = 'bar';
```

So with that all being said, if a dynamic variable name is *required* and a container object is not able to be used, `eval` can be used to create/access/modify a dynamic variable name.

```
var evalString = ['var', variableName, '=', String.quote(variableValue), ';'].join(' ')
eval( evalString );
```

Comment: Note to self: ES2015 introduced some new [object initializer features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) which should be added to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use square bracket notation in Javascript:

```
variable = "name_of_variable";
window[variable] = "somevalue";
```

You can do this with any object in Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = "var_name";
var obj = {};
obj[name] = 'value';
alert(obj.var_name);
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using associative arrays to do whatever you're trying to do as they are significantly cleaner and easier to debug.

However if you really insist, you can use `eval()` to accomplish this:

```
variable = "name_of_variable";
eval(variable + " = \"somevalue\""); // this will work, but please do not do it
alert(name_of_variable);
```

**EDIT:** It his just come to my attention that a significantly easier (and better) way of doing this is by simply accessing the `window` object:

```
window[variable] = "somevalue";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WJCrB/

Comment: `eval` is The Canonical Wrong Tool for this, esp. since the bracket notation makes the same task both possible and easy.

Comment: @Piskvor: Edited my answer. However I'll leave the `eval()` method up there because it is a valid solution (albeit terrible, I agree).

Answer (score -3):

```
window['name_of_variable'] = 'somevalue';
```

or

```
eval('var ' + variable_name + ' = ' + variable_name + ';');
```

Beyond that, don't do this. Variable variables are NEVER a good idea and make it nearly impossible to debug problems when (invariably) things break.

Comment: -1 for even mentioning the accursed `eval`, waiting for eternity in its house at R'lyeh ;) Yes, *it* has its uses, but this is an ab-use case.

Comment: This isn't even a correct example of `eval`, you need quotes around the value.