# Javascript: how to access property whose name is dynamic?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript create variable from its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028035/javascript-create-variable-from-its-name)

The code below checks to see if the javascript object **form_errors** has the property whose name is specified by **this.name**, where **this** refers to a text input

```
if (form_errors.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
  alert(form_errors.<this.name>;
}
```

How can I access the property without hard-coding the property name but leaving in the generalized form **this.name** ? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
form_errors[this.name]
```

You can access any property of an object by passing in a string with its name. For instance, `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` have the same result.

Comment: Just keep in mind `foo['i-like-hyphens']` can only be accessed with brackets.

Comment: Actually in javascript everything is arrays. Even JSON are arrays with different data types. So Braces are the best option.

Comment: @abhishek, You're incorrect. Everything in JS is an `object`, it just happens that `arrays` are a special form of `object`. Try `typeof []` in the console.

Comment: @abhishek, aside from the type hierarchy remark, I'd say that whether to use brackets or the dot notation is a question of circumstances. In case of statical accesses, using the dot notation is 3 characters shorter and doesn't imply any strings (which is more refactor-friendly), so in my opinion, it's better to stick to it until you come to a point where it's impossible (such as the situation noted by Dennis, or OP's situation).