# JavaScript property access with for..in

Tags: javascript, properties

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) is asked, but it didn't meet the conditions I've met.

I know that to access a property I can use either point notation or bracket notation. An [article at jibbering.com](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) states the same, also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083558/875968). The [Specifiacation](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.2.1) says the same.

I have this example ( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a45Se/) ) and there is a difference:

```
var utils = {
    myString: "boo",
    myNumber: 99,
    justNULL: null
};

for (var i in utils) {
    document.write ( i + " = " + utils.i + "<br/>" ); //result - undefined
    document.write ( i + " = " + utils[i] + "<br/>" );//result - the actual value
}​
```

What I am missing here? Is it something about the usage of the for..in or the definition of the object?

Comment: The member access operator (the dot) _is_ slightly different... Anything that follows it must be a valid JavaScript identifier. So, for example, `obj.foo = 'bar';` works, but `obj.123 = 'bar';` does not, because identifiers can't start with a number. However, `obj['123'] = 'bar';` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's the usage of the point notation that is the problem.

You can't use a variable for the property name when you are using the point notation. The expression `utils.i` will access the property `i` in the object, it won't use the variable `i` for the name.

Comment: O, I didn't thought about this. 10x :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use utils[i] format here because i is a string and a string reference can not be used to access a property using the use object.property format.

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 'test';

obj.'foo' // doesn't work
obj['foo'] // works
```